# Remove module from template position (change to 'none')

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, positions

I have a simple problem: When a module is created it can be saved without a position (showing as position 'none' in the list). But once any position is set, it can apparently be only changed to another and not cleared back to 'none'.

Note that I do not want to unpublish the module. I want to use it by other means (creating a module instance in Gantry 5 layout manager).

I know I can re-create the module or create some hidden position for it, but it seems quite odd that the position couldn't be simply cleared when apparently modules without position can exist. Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is:

While you are editing the module, open the browser's console (Usually <kbd>F12</kbd> and click on `Console` tab), then type:

```
document.getElementById('jform_position').value = '';
```

in the console and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now you can save the module with an empty position AKA `none` postion.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, this does the trick. At first I thought it wasn't working because the displayed value didn't change, but when I inspected the elements, I realized the displayed text was not the `<select>` value that was changed by me. So when I saved the module, it was really saved with empty position.

Comment: @Matej - You're welcome. Glad it helped. Yes, you are right; actually the code changes the value of `select` element and does not affect on Bootstrap drop-down. So you'll see the changes after saving the module.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way (from what i know) to reset the module position to None but as you said you can create a new custom position named None or Empty and save the module on that position that way it won't be in your template.

That new custom position is saved as an Active Position and will be deleted only if no module has it.

If you really want to clear that position you can do it from the phpMyAdmin. Find the table prefix _modules search for your module and delete the position field.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug and should be fixed in version 3.7 please see [the bug info here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/13243)

As a work around you can remove the position in the database - look in the xxx_modules table for your module, there is a column called 'position' just delete the value in this column.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. I'm glad to hear this bug is going to be fixed soon.